# WPF XAML DataGrid Change Button Image Programmatically C#

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid

I have the following xaml code:

```
        <DataGrid CanUserReorderColumns="False" 
                  CanUserResizeColumns="False"
                  CanUserResizeRows="False" 
                  CanUserSortColumns="False"
                  SelectionMode="Extended" 
                  SelectionUnit="Cell"
                  Name="endpoints" 
                  AlternatingRowBackground="LightGray"
                  AlternationCount="2"
                  Margin="5"
                  Height="250"
                  ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True"
                  ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
                  ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
```

...

```
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn  Header="Validate" Width="*">
                        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <Button x:Name="validate" Click="validate_Click">
                                    <Image Source="{Binding validateImage}" Height="16" Width="16"/>
                                </Button>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

I populate each row of the DataGrid using a foreachloop:

```
endpoints.Items.Add(new endpointObjects() {... });
```

*validate_Click function*

```
    private void validate_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var currentRowIndex = endpoints.Items.IndexOf(endpoints.CurrentItem);
        var currentColIndex = endpoints.CurrentCell.Column.DisplayIndex;
        DataGridRow t = dataGridTools.GetRow(endpoints, currentRowIndex);
        var ip = (t.Item as endpointObjects).ip;
        var port = (t.Item as endpointObjects).port;

        MessageBox.Show("Validate Button Clicked: " + currentRowIndex + " | " + currentColIndex + " | " 
            + (t.Item as endpointObjects).isHost + " | " 
            + " | " + (t.Item as endpointObjects).ip
            + ":" + (t.Item as endpointObjects).port);
    }
```

DataGrid View 
[image: DataGrid View]

I just do not seem to be able to address the image. I was hoping for something like Javascript DOM method as shown below.

```
[datagrid] > [button name] > [image].Image Source = "images\newImage.png";
endpoints.edit.Image.Source = "images\newImage.png";
```

So when I click on the button/image it triggers a function (in this case, validate_Click) which performs a particular task and depending on the result of that task change to the button image to another image.

Very new to all of this, so any assistance to help me understand where I am going wrong would be greatly appreciated.

**UPDATE - RESOLVED**

This was resolved with the following 2 lines:

```
        var image =  (Image)(sender as Button).Content;
        image.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("images/tick.png", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
```

Example implementation of basic function shown below:

```
    private void validate_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var currentRowIndex = endpoints.Items.IndexOf(endpoints.CurrentItem);
        var currentColIndex = endpoints.CurrentCell.Column.DisplayIndex;
        DataGridRow t = dataGridTools.GetRow(endpoints, currentRowIndex);
        var ip = (t.Item as endpointObjects).ip;
        var port = (t.Item as endpointObjects).port;
        var image =  (Image)(sender as Button).Content;
        image.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("images/tick.png", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
        MessageBox.Show("Validate Button Clicked: " + currentRowIndex + " | " + currentColIndex + " | "
            + (t.Item as endpointObjects).isHost + " | "
            + (t.Item as endpointObjects).FTRname
            + " | " + (t.Item as endpointObjects).ip
            + ":" + (t.Item as endpointObjects).port
            + " | " + image.Source.ToString()
            );
    }
```

Comment: you can use converters for this to do. check the following sample code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `validate_Click`method the `sender`is the button the user clicked on. Therefore you can get the Image control by casting the buttons content.

```
var image = (Image)((sender as Button).Content);
```

And then setting the ImageSource:

```
image.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(...));
```

Comment: This was exactly what I was after and what you describe makes sense as it is a child of the button. I'll update the final code in the question. Thank you!

Comment: I'm glad I could help.

Comment: This is the wrong approach. Setting `image.Source` replaces the previously assigned Binding, `Source="{Binding validateImage}"`, and any subsequent changes of validateImage are ignored. Instead of setting image.Source, change validateImage.

Answer (score 0):

try this code,

```
public class ImageSourceConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            if (value != null)
            {
                string code = value as string;
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(code))
                    return string.Format("/pathof the image/{0}.png", code);
            }
            return value;
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            return value;
        }
    }
```

Comment: given the detail in the question, could you explain to me how I would go about implementing this class, I seem to be unable to reach the image element to set the Source tag. Perhaps I am missing something?

Comment: if you have patience you can read this document how to use value convertors https://wpftutorial.net/ValueConverters.html

Comment: Thanks for the link, however converting objects is not the issue I am having. It's addressing the image tag `Source` parameter held within the button tag that I'm having trouble with. As you can see in my code I already do object conversion in the validate_Click function `(t.Item as endpointObjects).isHost` -  I need to address the `Source` Tag in DataGrid > Button > Image. Sorry if I have not been clear.

Comment: in wpf you can convert the grid cell to a button type . so we can implement this method